# logstash name fields dynamically

Tags: filter, logstash

i have a dynamical field,  the field format looks like

```
A-B-C::D_[randomNum]
```

the field is dynamic because the randonNUM ,
i want to change the '-' to '_' and remove the [randomNUM]
and it's will be looks like as follow,

```
  A_B_C::D
```

Is there any plugin / strategy to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this with a `mutate/gsub` filter

```
filter {
  mutate {
    gsub => [
      # replace random num suffix
      "fieldname", "_\d+", "",
      # replace all dashes with underscores
      "fieldname", "-", "_"
    ]
  }
}
```

Make sure to replace `fieldname` with your actual field name.

**UPDATE**

Given your comments, it turned out it's the field names that are dynamic and not the value. For this reason, you cannot use the above solution but the next one should work, i.e. using the [`ruby` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-ruby.html):

```
filter {
  ruby {
    code => "
      newhash = {}
      event.to_hash.each {|key, value| 
        if key =~ /^CISCO/ then
            newkey = key.gsub(/_\d+/, '').gsub('-', '_')
            newhash[newkey] = event[key]
            event.remove(key)
        end
      }
      newhash.each {|key,value|
        event[key] = value
      }
    "
  }
}
```

After this filter runs, your event will have the field `A_B_C::D` instead of the original `A-B-C::D_num`

Comment: hi Val, thanks for your reply !  I'm sorry I wasn't more clear in the question.     i don't how to set the field  because of the randomNum . that all I can specific is the prefix of the fieldname .   like  "A-B-C::D_*"

Comment: So that's your field name and not your field value, is that right?

Comment: YES, the field name is not field value. for my example ,  the output is looks like  A-B-C::D_[randomNum] => field_value......

Comment: What's your input, i.e. where are you getting your data from?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111835/discussion-between-stefansaye-and-val).