# Ruby - getting value in logstash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logstash

i have a field and value output looks like

```
A::field_1_2_3_4_22_5_6_7_8_365  => 6
```

because the field name is "dynamical" because of contain ip and port.
how to using ruby to get value from field name and add field for it ? it's will be looks like

```
A::field => 6
bIP => 1.2.3.4
bport => 22
cIP => 5.6.7.8
cport => 365
```

any help will be appreciated!!thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an answer for a very similar question: [logstash name fields dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37203138/logstash-name-fields-dynamically/37203865#37203865)

For this precise case, the `ruby` filter needs to be a bit more involved in order to capture different things

```
filter {
  ruby {
    code => "
      newhash = {}
      event.to_hash.each {|key, value| 
        re = /(\w::[a-z]+)_(\d+_\d+_\d+_\d+)_(\d+)_(\d+_\d+_\d+_\d+)_(\d+)/
        if key =~ re then
            field, bIP, bport, cIP, cport = key.match(re).captures
            newhash[field] = event[key]
            newhash['bIP'] = bIP.gsub('_', '.')
            newhash['bport'] = bport
            newhash['cIP'] = cIP.gsub('_', '.')
            newhash['cport'] = cport

            event.remove(key)
        end
      }
      newhash.each {|key,value|
        event[key] = value
      }
    "
  }
}
```

So if you have a field like `"A::field_1_2_3_4_22_5_6_7_8_365" => "6"` in your event, your event will then contain the following fields:

```
{
      "A::field" => "6",
           "bIP" => "1.2.3.4",
         "bport" => "22",
           "cIP" => "5.6.7.8",
         "cport" => "365"
}
```

Comment: Have you been able to try this out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the following code:

```
field_name = 'A::field_1_2_3_4_22_5_6_7_8_365'
fields = field_name.split("_")
bID = "#{fields[1]}.#{fields[2]}.#{fields[3]}.#{fields[4]}"
bport = "#{fields[5]}"
bID = "#{fields[6]}.#{fields[7]}.#{fields[8]}.#{fields[9]}"
bport = "#{fields[10]}"
```

Comment: the field name is dynamical because of ip and port. so i cannot specific the field name. it's only can specific the prefix of the field name is "A::field_"

Comment: How do you get an A::field_ field?  What creates this field and how can your code "know" about it?  Can you provide a real code example that shows how it's created (or acquired) and used?

Comment: The HARD part of this is to get the name of the field, and it's necessary to know what the field is to know how to get the name.  It might not even be possible to get the name in some cases.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe i've not understooden this quite correctly but you can use arrays and method .push for adding:

```
Array=[1, 2, 5, 7]
@n = [3, 4, 6]
Array.push(@n) => Array=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```